# Check if previous clicked value is inside an array

Tags: jquery

I have a list with different categories. All the list item are clickable. I want the user to pick between 1 and 3 items.  They can toggle their choice, but maximum is alway 3. So far, so good.

Where it get tricky for me, is that I have some special categories that can't be combined with any others.

When a user click on one of these, all the other categories deselect and they can't add any other, (these item have only 1 category selection possible)

Exemple:

Let's say "Car" is a special category. If they click on Car, everything else deselect, Car is selected, **and they can't select anything else. BUT they can click again on Car to deselect it, and from there the logic start over.**

What's missing in my code is the part in bold just above this.

My code:

```
$j('.chooseCat li').on('click',function(){
   var $this = $j(this); //list item clicked
   var catId =  $this.children("a").attr("rel"); // list item id
   var specialCat = ['6','36','63']; 

   if ($this.hasClass("selected")) {
      $this.removeClass("selected");
      $j("#categorySuggestions p.error").hide("fast")
   } else {
      if( $j.inArray(catId, specialCat) !== -1  ) {
         $j('.chooseCat li').removeClass("selected");
         $this.addClass("selected");
      } else {
         if ($j('.chooseCat li.selected').length <= 2){
            $this.addClass("selected");
         } else {
             $j("#categorySuggestions p.error").show("fast").html("You cannot select any more categories");
         }
      }
   }
});
```

A working jsFiddle of where Iam at: http://jsfiddle.net/nfQum/9/

Comment: Can you point out the part in bold.. ??

Comment: Can you select more than one special category? Say 16 and 55 in your example?

Comment: @João Silva - so if you select cat 16 you cant select anything else. Or you can click again on cat 16 to deselect it, and from there it starts over. 3 normal, or as soon as you click on a special one, it deselect the others and cant select more. I know its kinda confusing lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added this part of the code which iterates thru the specialCat and removes the class associated with the. The problem you are encountering is that you are trying to removeClass for the a tag, where as the class was applied to the li instead..

```
if ($.inArray(catId, specialCat) > -1) {
            $.each(specialCat, function(i) {
                $('.chooseCat li').find('a[rel=' + specialCat[i]+ ']').parent().removeClass('selected');
            });
            $this.addClass("selected");
        }
```

check this [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nfQum/13/)

Let me know if this is what you are looking for..

Comment: mmm almost. Let's say you select 2 normal category, and then you select a special one. what it shoud do is: the 2 normal cat are deselected, the special one is selected and then you cant select anything else. But you can click again on the special one, and it deselect it

Comment: so basically you have two choices:
1: you select 1 to 3 normal cat or 2: you select one special and cant select more!

Comment: @Lelly .. I have UPDATED FIDDLE above for you with a little bit of explanation.. Check it and let me know if this is the functionality you are looking for..

Comment: Yes it's perfect, thanks for the effort you put in the answer!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/zD32M/4/ (all comments inside)

http://jsfiddle.net/RmqJ6/ - A bit harder thing with Class :)

http://jsfiddle.net/RmqJ6/2/ - and this if you want switch between special cats.

If you will need id`s of your element just take a ids array. So you have all selected values.

here you go. Sorry for total rewrite, and better way is to write a constructor for this thing, so you could use it multiple times. Have fun.

By the way rel is nice, but better use data attributes especially with jQuery (it much faster if you need it not only one time).

Comment: I think almost close , except that you can select a special category but not a normal one when a currently selected is a special category one..

Comment: A thoght it was the case - "Let's say you select 2 normal category, and then you select a special one. what it shoud do is: the 2 normal cat are deselected, the special one is selected and then you cant select anything else"

Comment: actually, you're both right. When I wrote my question, I was thinking of a behavior just like FLops answer. But it actually make more sense to have it like sushanth reddy describe. So when there's a special category selected, you can only select another special cat. But only 1 can be selected (not both).

Comment: Take a look at last one - there would be much easyer to control it.

Comment: @Flops can you please update your Fiddle to reflect what I just said in my last comment?  and thank you so much for the effort you put in this, I really appreciate this, as I had no idea how to do it.